# Google Cloud SQL Error: unknown host name

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to do the following tutorial to try to get the spring petclinic application running on google app engine. The actions described in the tuorial are being done on the google cloud shell:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-spring-petclinic-on-app-engine-cloudsql

at step 7:

```
./mvnw -Drun.profiles=mysql spring-boot:run
```

however I run into the following error

Error Summary (Cause):

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: google: No address associated with hostname
            at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
            ... 85 common frames omitted
```

Full error can be found at:

https://pastebin.com/cuYzVmsa

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-petclinic</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <name>petclinic</name>

  <properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Web dependencies -->
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
    <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>

    <cobertura.version>2.7</cobertura.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.sql/mysql-socket-factory -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring and Spring Boot dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
                <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Databases - Uses HSQL by default -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- caching -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
      <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- webjars -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end of webjars -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Spring Boot Actuator displays build-related information
              if a META-INF/build-info.properties file is present -->
            <goals>
              <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <additionalProperties>
                <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
              </additionalProperties>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <check />
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Spring Boot Actuator displays build-related information if a git.properties
        file is present at the classpath -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</dateFormat>
          <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
          <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties
          </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
          <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
          <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/resources/css</cssDestinationFolder>
          <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
          <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
          <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/less</contextFolder>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <!-- integrate maven-cobertura-plugin to project site -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <formats>
            <format>html</format>
          </formats>
          <check />
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: did you create that database? can you access it via a different method (maybe the google sql management pane)? From a different SO post, I see that a Google SQL URL would rather look like "jdbc:google:mysql://festive-shark-90408:daily-joy-project/database?user=joys"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446212/i-cant-connect-to-my-google-cloud-sql-database-from-my-deployed-backend-servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the EXACT same issue.
Fortunately, I was able to figure it out thanks to one of the comments on the tutorial's thread.

This line on step 5 of the tutorial is incorrect:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/petclinic?cloudSqlInstance=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

Instead you should have:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/petclinic?cloudSqlInstance=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

It's really unfortunate. Hope to have helped.